# PHP and persistent connections

Tags: php, mongodb, persistent-connection

Whenever I open a persistent connection to the DB , if the DB daemon crashes and is then restarted, 30% of new connections to the daemon will result in a broken pipe error.

This is fixable by changing the persistent connection handle, but it needs to be done manually. Is there a solution that can fix the broken pipe errors without changing the handle?

Comment: If you have a reproducible case, please submit it to the Google Group (http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user). The developer of the PHP driver (Kristina) is on there nearly every day. She should be able to help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with

> DB daemon crashes and is then restarted

This is what you need to fix... Look through the logs to find the problem...

Finding alternative fix is equivalent of ***applying a bandage on a broken arm***.
[image]

Comment: The DB server has never crashed before. But if it does, the "broken pipe" error will bring the whole application down.

Comment: This problem occurs when mongo replica set master, for example.

Comment: This happens when the daemon doesn't crash as well, like when a network connection error occurs.  In this case looking at the logs would be futile (however never a bad place to start for any reason).